# c# asp.net how can i change the image url of button (it's type is image ) when i click the button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I created an gridview it has favorite button and I want to change the url of it when i click on it. how can i do it?

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="446px" AllowPaging="True" 
            onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand1" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:ImageField AlternateText="Add To Favorites" Visible=false 
                        DataImageUrlFormatString="&quot;~/images/favorites.png&quot;" 
                        FooterText="Add To Favorites" HeaderText="Add To Favorites">
                        <FooterStyle Width="10px" />
                    </asp:ImageField>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="AddComment" ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Comment" ImageUrl="~/images/commentt.png" Text="Comment" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Share"  ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Share with Friends" ImageUrl="~/images/openshare.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Text="Share" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                     <asp:ButtonField CommandName="ShareGroups"  ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Share with Groups"   ImageUrl="~/images/openshare.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Text="Share" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                  <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Favorites" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/StarEmpty.png" CommandName="Favorite" 
                        Text="Add to Favorites" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <FooterStyle Height="20px" />
                    <HeaderStyle Width="3px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Image"  CommandName="Mail" HeaderText="Send Mail" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/email-icon.png.jpg" Text="Send Mail" 
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" InsertVisible="False" >

                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>

                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="View" Text="View Rss" 
                        HeaderText="View Rss" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                    <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="15px" />

                    </asp:ButtonField>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="RSS_Title" HeaderText="RSS_Title"
                        SortExpression="RSS_Title" />
                   <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
                    Value='<%#Eval("RSS_ID")%>'/>

            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My c# codes are below

```
  if (e.CommandName == "Favorite")
        {
           //GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].

            string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(sValue);
            Session["SelectedRSS"] = sValue;

            DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
            bool res = db.CheckFavorites(id, User_Name);

            // if favorite rss  doesnot exist
            if (!res)
            {
                Boolean result = db.addFavorite(id, User_Name);

        DataSet selectedRSS = db.getRSS(id);
        DataTable dt = selectedRSS.Tables[0];
        DataRow row = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            row = dt.Rows[i];
            countOfFavorite = Convert.ToInt32(row[3].ToString());

        }
        countOfFavorite++;

                Boolean result1 = db.increaseFavoriteCount(id, countOfFavorite);

                // rssi favori olarak user dosyasına kaydet;


            }


        }
```

Comment: I could not change the image url of favorite button when i click it(not addto favorite it is favorites button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, assign an ID(**favBtn**, in my case) to the Favorite button field like as follows:

```
asp:ButtonField ID="favBtn" ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Favorites" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/StarEmpty.png" CommandName="Favorite" 
                    Text="Add to Favorites" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">

if (e.CommandName == "Favorite")
{
    // ...
    // Code Updated here
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)row.Controls[0].Controls[0];
    ib.ImageUrl = "~/images/something.png"; // change to your new image

    // ...
}
```

It should work but can't gurantee. :)

Comment: Error 19 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\RSS_proje\RSS_proje\WebApplication2-5.2\RssGrid.aspx.cs 37 49 WebApplication2

Comment: Also, I have to change only the column which is clicked

Comment: also, I cannot insert <id> tag

Comment: I have update code a little bit. pls check whether it works or not.

Comment: If my solution served your purpose, I recommend you to accept this as Answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry , I said that when I insert <id> tag it does not work. I cannot solve this problem and I don't know the reason of problem.

Comment: I think, withould ID field, it should also work. Please give a try, if still the problem exists. In that case, you don't need to insert <id> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `src` property in an onclick event?

```
onclick="this.src = 'http://mysite.com/images/differentimage.jpg'"
```

In server-side code you would do something like this:

```
myImageButton.ClientClick = "this.src = '" + ResolveUrl("~/images/someotherimage.jpg") + "';";
```

In server-side HTML markup you can do:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="this.src='http://mysite.com/images/someotherimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: How can i identify myimagebutton?. Also, Mybutton is not imagebutton

Comment: You can find your button control in the binding events with FindControl()

Answer (score 0):

Modify your favorite column as below

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Favorites" ImageUrl='<%# GetCorrectImg(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsFavirated"))) %>'
            CommandName="Favorite" Text="Add to Favorites" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <FooterStyle Height="20px" />
            <HeaderStyle Width="3px" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:ButtonField>
```

In this function GetCorrectImg(IsFavirated) u can set values by which u can set logic which image need to be set. define below function in your code behind

```
public string GetActiveInactiveImg(Boolean IsFavirated)
    {
        string retVal = "~/images/buttons/StarEmpty.png";


        if (IsFavirated == true)
        {
            retVal = "~/images/buttons/ChangeImage.gif";
        }
    else 
        {
            retVal = "~/images/buttons/StarEmpty.png";
        }


        return retVal;
    }
```

Bind the grid again once your ItemCommand event is fired.

Hope this will help.

Comment: what do i  write  to ("pass the column name") I don't understand sorry can you give an example ?

Comment: need to pass your bind column like <%# GetCorrectImg(Convert.ToInteger32(Eval("RSSID"))) %> .

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

It gives an error how can i solve it ?                           Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField does not have a DataBinding event.

Comment: what is the criteria for changing the favorite button image ?  you have to pass like <%# GetCorrectImg(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("RSS_ID"))) %>

Comment: I actually want to mark as favorite the rss items and When I add the rss as a favorite , the image url of the button should be changed

Comment: SO Inside the function you can check by Rss_id that this item is mark it as favorite or not ..based on result you can return image url as shown in function. i m going to change the function in my answer based on your requirement.

Comment: i have modify my answer ..pls try that. when u bind the grid ..you can fetch one extra column value for rss that is "IsFavirated". that will take care of all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9781/discussion-between-leventkalay92-and-prakash-patani)

Answer (score -1):

you Must to Create new Folder and R.Click in the new Folder add select Exist item , choice the Pictures and make image & Button , double Click into the Button write this Code ( image1.imageurl="example.jpg"; , then run the Web click the button the image will change to the another Picture .